# Can a scrapy callback function point to the same function in which the request is spawned

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy to crawl a site.

I have code similar to this:

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(url=example_url,  
                                callback=self.parse,
                                cookies={'store_language':'en'},
                                endpoint='render.html',
                                args={'wait': 5}, 
                            )  

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            self.extract_data_from_page(response)

            if (next_link_still_on_page(response):
                next_url = grok_next_url(response)

                yield SplashRequest(url=next_url, 
                                callback=self.parse,
                                cookies={'store_language':'en'},
                                endpoint='render.html',
                                args={'wait': 5}, 
                            )  

        except Exception:
            pass


    def extract_data_from_page(self, response):
        pass


    def next_link_still_on_page(self,response):
        pass


    def grok_next_url(self, response):
        pass
```

In the `parse()` method, the callback function is `parse()` is this to be frowned upon (e.g. a logic bug causing potential stack overflow?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use the same callback. From a technical perspective it isn't an issue. Especially if the yielded request is of the same nature as the current one, then it should ideally reuse the same logic.

However, from a *person-who-has-to-read-the-source-code* perspective, it is better to have separate parsers for *different* tasks or page types (the whole single responsibility principle).

---

Let me illustrate with an example. Let's say you have a listing website (jobs, products, whatever) and you have two main classes of URLs:

- Search result pages: `.../search?q=something&page=2`
- Item pages: `.../item/abc`

The search result page contains *pagination links* and *items*. Such a page would spawn two kinds of requests to:

1. Parse the next page
2. Parse the item

The Item page will not spawn another request.

So now you *can* stuff all of that into the same parser and use it for every request:

```
def parse(self, response):
    if 'search' in response.url:
        for item in response.css('.item'):
            # ...
            yield Request(item_url, callback=self.parse)

        # ...
        yield Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)

    if 'item' in response.url:
        yield {
            'title': response.css('...'),
            # ...
        }
```

That is obviously a very condensed example, but as it grows it will become harder to follow along.

Instead, break up the different page parsers:

```
def parse_search(self, response):
    for item in response.css('.items'):
        yield Request(item_url, callback=self.parse_item)

    next_url = response.css('...').get()
    yield Request(next_url, callback=self.parse_search)


def parse_item(self, response):
    yield {
        'title': response.css('...'),
        # ...
    }
```

So basically, if it's a matter of "another of the same kind of page" then it's normal to use the same callback in order to reuse the same logic. If the next request requires a different kind of parsing, rather make a separate parser.